# It is kosher to open similar questions and then answer them yourself?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

I asked 2 questions with slight variations:
One on how to get your [Seed data into the testing environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861075/how-can-i-load-seeds-rb-into-the-test-database-without-breaking-factorygirl) without breaking FactoryGirl and then a second on how to use FactoryGirl to [populate the Seeds.rb file using a helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881750/rails-how-to-link-seeds-rb-to-a-helper) in the spec directory.

I managed to play around enough to answer one, and thus answer the other but is it acceptable to answer multiple of your own questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to do that. [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

A little restraint in that is probably advisable, though.

Comment: "A little restraint" meaning "please follow the established custom regarding duplicates just as you would expect others to do in posting *their* questions", right?

Comment: Well, also "Don't post poor questions just because you already know the answer" and "If you answer 50 of your own questions within 30 days, the questions and answers better be really good".

Comment: I did not know my own answer at the time of posting the question.
I was really stuck for a good while before asking.

Comment: Yes, and I wouldn't call it an exact duplicate. Nevertheless, the question this has been closed as a duplicate of does cover the ground too (and more questions linked from there). The point is, it's okay to answer your own question _even if you know the answer before asking_, so it's fine to answer it if you found the answer after posting the question. If your answer is good, you will get some deserved upvotes, whether you knew the answer before or found it later.